# HTTPS and FormAssembly

Tags: forms, https, response

We are using a FormAssembly page to collect feedback - it's hosted within an IFrame on the side of our site's master page.

The thing is, that some parts of our site are HTTPS - viewing and posting the form is ok in HTTPS, but the problem comes with the "thank you" page - we are using the configurable custom thank you page (configured within FormAssembly iteself).

Is there are way we can send the desired response page up (perhaps via a hidden field within the posted form?) - this way we can send the HTTPS link for the HTTPS version of the form and the normal HTTP link for the HTTP form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the FormAssembly forums and it seems that it is supported via "Aliases", which is a "Pro" feature... seems I have to upgrade :s

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into and solved this exact problem. I am embedding formAssembly code onto my https site and was having problems populating hidden fields. I was able to get the hidden fields to populate by changing all of formAssembly's http references to https. However, that broke my thank you page. To fix the thank you page and keep my hidden fields populating, i changed only www.tfaforms.com/responses/processor back to http: and everything worked.